# Proper way to execute a function from a JavaScript created button?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm creating some simple buttons on a web page using Javascript and need to call a function when they are clicked.  I've come up with the following example that works based on searching for answers.  However, it seems wrong to create a function just to call a function.  I wasn't able to successfully directly call the function "click_button" which is elsewhere in the script any other way.

This works:

```
my_button.onclick = function (){
    click_button(my_button.value);
    }
```

These don't work:

```
// This executes on first run, but not when clicked.
my_button.onclick = click_button(my_button.value);
// This doesn't do anything when clicked.
my_button.onclick = "click_button(my_button.value);";
```

Is the top example the proper way to call a function from a button click in JavaScript?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the first example is the right one and you could also add event listener using this syntax `my_button.addEventListener("click", myScript);` look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: Simply because `onclick` should be `callback(function)` to work when triggered / fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you assign a reference to a function that should be called when the button is clicked. This is correct.

In the second example, you assign the result of the click_button function to the onclick. So when your code is read by the engine, it executes your click_button function and assigns the resulting value to the onclick. So when you click your button, there is no function to execute, just a value.

In the third example you just assign a string to your onclick. This can't work.

So yes the first way is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by explaining why your last two examples do **not** work:

```
my_button.onclick = click_button(my_button.value);
```

This will execute the `click_button()` function right away, and will assign whatever the function returns to `my_button.onclick`

```
my_button.onclick = "click_button(my_button.value);";
```

This just sets the value of `my_button.onclick` to a string. The button's onclick property is not expecting a string with javascript code inside, and it will not evaluate it in that way.

---

You can see how the `onclick` property works here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

The function assigned to `onclick` will be passed a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). Your `click_button` function takes a value as a parameter, so as of right now you can't simply assign the function itself to `onclick` like so:

```
my_button.onclick = click_button // won't be given my_button.value
```

because the value passed to be will be a `MouseEvent`, not what you expect.

If you modify the `click_button` function to not require the value parameter, then you could do something like:

```
function click_button () {
    // Do stuff using this.value or my_button.value directly
}

my_button.onclick = click_button
```

Otherwise, if you want to be able to pass `my_button.value` to the function, you need to wrap it in another function, as you do correctly in the first example.

---

As @Mikey pointed out in the comments, you can get the value by using `this.value` inside of the function. The MDN docs state that `this` will be set to the element within the function.

Comment: Good answer. In your last example, he could also access the value with `this.value` inside the function.

Comment: @Mikey Ooh! Awesome, I didn't realize that. Now I see in the MDN docs it does mention that `this` will be the element. I'll update my answer.